# Unable to Launch Google Chrome using default/custom profile in Selenium WebDriver that undergo http basic authentication

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, profile

Following methods are not working properly.
Since GRID is used, **capability** is set as **null** here.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");   
DesiredCapabilities capability=null;
```

**Method 1:**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=C:/Users   /username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

**Method 2:**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
String chromeProfile = "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application   /chrome.exe"; 
ArrayList<String> switches = new ArrayList<String>(); 
switches.add("C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default" + chromeProfile); 
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", switches); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

If you face such error:

**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally**

Then try to create a new Chrome profile and execute tests.

1. Copy the folder, `'User Data'`
2. Paste & Rename the folder on the same location. `e.g., New User`
3. Now, locate the directory, `C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/New User`
4. If you like to test the profile, then bookmark some of the sites & observe them on next run.

Answer (score 0):

1 Set the chromedriver property in starting the node. My approach:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 15 -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=15 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=lib\chromedriver.exe
```

2 Inside the code my approach:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-maximized"));
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

3 loading the HTTP basic auth page:

```
String username = "Pavel";
String password = "Omgtoosecrettotellyou";
driver.get("http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" +"your-site.com");
```